# Apple Music Membership

Tags: apple-music

If I cancel my apple music membership will I lose all my music that i downloaded from the app? Is there any way I could keep the music ? I only need to switch my App Store country since I am moving to Boston from Indonesia..

Answer (score 1):

You won’t lose the music you have downloaded, but **you also won’t be able to play the music** (unlesss you have purchased them separately on the iTunes Store).